# Fire event when text in textarea is changed

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

Does anyone know how to pickup if the text within a `<textarea>` has been modified using jQuery?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to bind the `change` and `keyup` on the text area.

The `change` will prevent context-menu pasting, and the `keyup` will fire for every keystroke.

```
$('#textarea').bind('change keyup', function() {
  alert('Handler for .change() called.');
});
```

Comment: For textareas this only fires when the textarea is blurred. Hard to say if that's OK for the OP.

Comment: Yes i think we need to bind two events here change and keyup. Change for pasting text and keyup for keyboard events. I am changing my answer please take a look

Comment: Using `alert` makes it difficult to test a response to a continuous stream of typing.  It is better to update the DOM in a noticeable way.

Comment: I've just called this within a `<script>` tag at the start of the page and it doesn't seem to do anything when I press a key up.

Comment: Please do that while the whole document is ready. you have to put it in the end of the page. before closing the `<body>` and you can declare it in `$(document).ready(function(){});`

Comment: I just put it in `<textarea onkeypress="jsmethod();">` in the end... Thanks

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/NpB2U/ `keydown` is probably ideal for continuous change.  `keypress` and `keyup` work for other circumstances.  `change` and `blur` are candidates if you only want to analyze changes after they have finished typing.

Comment: This looks like what I need. If I just write `<script type="text/javascript">$('#themessage').keypress(function() {  alert('ahh'); });</script>` in the body, should it work?

Answer (score 0):

Use the .change method;

```
<textarea id="YourId"></textarea>
```

Jquery;

```
$('#YourId').change(function() {
    //Do something
});
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's `keyup()` allows you to detect changes when the keyboard is used to enter data.

```
$( "#watched_textarea" ).keyup( function() {
    // Perform an action
});
```

See it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/vtCWK/

If you want to detect other types of changes (pasting or cutting of text, for example, you will also want to use `.change()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txt" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Columns="50" Rows="5" />
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function () {
            jQuery('#txt').blur(function () { alert(jQuery(this).val()); });
        });
    </script>
```

you can try like this....